# hard drive recovery after low-level reformat

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

I've reformatted my hard drive and reinstalled Windows but nothing else. I've looked at several hard drive recovery options and many say they can recover data after reformatting but the reformat I did was a low-level reformat, not the quick format. Is it technically possible to recover files after a low-level reformat?

Thanks

Comment: If money were no issue it might be possible to recover the data.  If you were a spy from an enemy government your government would spend a million dollars they would probably get the data back.

Comment: Are you asking if there's any method that has a non-zero chance of recovering the data? Or are you asking if there's any method that's likely to recover the data? And with what level of resources used?

Comment: What kind of "low-level reformat", precisely?

Comment: I wondered the same thing as grawity.  I suspect you just mean you didn't do the "quick format", but if it was a software format such as from (or while installing) Windows, that's not a low-level format. In fact, it's hard to low-level format a drive these days;  Seagate says the equivalent is to 0-fill (http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/203931en ), but I'd say the best you'd get is to use UBAN with at least 3 passes. If you meant you used a tool like UBAN, though, then it is equivalent to a low-level format and almost impossible to recover.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep you guys informed; thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically ( for example for security companies with special tools), it's maybe possible to recover data. But for a normal user: **No, it's not possible.**

Don't worry. Normal users aren't able to recover the data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is wrong - You can't do a low level format in Windows, so what was meant was a full format.  You may be able to use Testdisk to recover some data in some cases - even with a full format - but this depends on the way the format was implemented.

(For those that doubt this, google g=c800:5 )

Comment: Actually you can do a low level if you write 0's to the drive.

Comment: @moab We obviously have very different understanding of what a low level format means.

Comment: Yes an old term, but that is low as it gets on a modern hard drive